# jPlayer flash does not play in IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, jplayer

I cannot find out why my jPlayer installation does not work in IE when I use the flash plugin. I am using IE10 on Windows 8, but it doesn't work in any modus, except when I set the solution to HTML5. In that case, it works only in IE10 and 9.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong here?

The javascript I use to start the player:

```
var stream = { mp3:"http://stream125.kerkomroep.nl:8005/K11015" };
var player = $("#jquery_jplayer_1");
player.jPlayer({
    errorAlerts:true,
    swfPath:"/jplayer/",
    supplied:"mp3",
    preload:"none",
    solution:'flash',
    wmode:"window"
});
player.jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
player.jPlayer( "play" );
```

The demo can be found on: http://tmp.hjts.nl/jplayer/index.html. (Click on the button "Play" to start playing)

Comment: Got this error when I tried it in Chrome: `jPlayer 2.2.0 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!jPlayer's Flash fallback is not configured correctly, or a command was issued before the jPlayer Ready event. Details: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'fl_setAudio_mp3'Check your swfPath option and that Jplayer.swf is there.Context: /jplayer/Jplayer.swf`. It seems to be more of a linkage issue than a code issue.

Comment: Using jPlayer 2.4.0 in javascript in my webpage. It works perfectly in Firefox 25. Doesn't work at all in IE 10. Not getting any script errors.